# How to show the request in one line?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a select and the response of this one shows me the data like this:

```
field 1 | field 2 | field 3 | field 4
--------------------------------------
  red   |  null   |  null   |  null
  null  |  blue   |  null   |  null
  null  |  null   |  green  |  null
  null  |  null   |  null   |  yellow
```

It is like a patron and it is always like this.
I am trying the get the data only in one line, avoiding `nulls` but i am so lost, i don't know how to do it.

Like this:

```
field 1 | field 2 | field 3 | field 4
--------------------------------------
  red   |  blue   |  green  |  yellow
```

Can someone give me a hand or some tips?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide some information about your select.

Comment: Do you mean something like `select max(field1), max(field2), max(field3), max(field4) from (your query)`?

Comment: @Paplusc - the answer above is ok, as far as you are sure that there is a single value, which is <> null per column. If this is not the case - you'll end up with missing data in the result set. If you're not sure about the data, instead of `MAX()`, you should use `LISTAGG()`, in order to get all not null statements into the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MIN` or `MAX` function to make it. 
if you want to get no rows contain a `NULL`

```
select MIN(field1), MIN(field2), MIN(field3), MIN(field4) 
from T
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d077d/1

Comment: It did the work, i could fix it using MAX(). :) thank you very much!